# Cannot get the "elif" conditional statement after "if" statement to work on Python's alien example for List of Dictionaries

Tags: python

The program is able to run through the iteration of the first if statement however it does not execute through the elif statement and continues to output the yellow and green statement.`

`aliens = []

```
for alien_number in range(30):
     new_alien = {'color':'green','points':5,'speed':'slow'}
     aliens.append(new_alien)

for alien in aliens[0:3]:
    if alien['color'] == 'green':
        alien['color'] = 'yellow'
        alien['speed'] = 'medium'
        alien['points'] = 10  

    elif alien['color'] == 'yellow': 
        alien['color'] = 'red' 
        alien['speed'] = 'fast' 
        alien['points'] = 15

for alien in aliens[:7]:
    print(alien)

print("...")

print(f'Total number of aliens: {len(aliens)}')

print('------------------------------\n')
```

#No red aliens in was placed in the output????????``

Comment: You've initialized list `aliens` with 30 exactly same dictionaries where `'color'` key value equals `'green'`. Then you iterate over first 3 items of `aliens` and check whether value of `'color'` key is `'green'` or `'yellow'`. Why do you expect that any item will have `'yellow'` value?

Comment: You seem to be confusing `if`/`elif` with two consecutive `if` statements.  They are not the same.

Comment: Python will run only 1 of the conditional suites in an `if` / elif / else`  statement. All aliens start of green and even though the first `if` changes the color to yellow, the elif doesn't run because the if already ran.

Comment: How would the code be made to show the red aliens? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try to add an 'else' statement after the 'elif'

Comment: This won't help.  All of the colors are "green" at the start.